# How to display section-container

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundation 4 and am currently trying to do the following:

I'm using the [section-container horizontal-nav](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html) and was wondering if anyone knows the configuration to get the section container to display its content first by default instead of hiding it until it's been clicked?  So when the page loads, the section will be shown first until the user clicks on "Section 1".

```
 <div class="section-container horizontal-nav" data-section="horizontal-nav">
 <section>
<p class="title" data-section-title>
    <a href="#">Section 1 </a>
</p>
<div class="content" data-section-content>
  <ul class="side-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about using section as a horizontal nav-bar? And that you want the dropdown menu to be shown when your page loads, so it's like the user has already clicked on it?

Comment: The section is placed as a horizontal nav-bar and I'd like for it to be shown when the page loads as if the user has already clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding active into the class attribute?

```
<div class="content active" data-section-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond!  Yeah, I tried adding 'active' for the data section content but it doesn't appear to do anything

Answer (score 0):

> The section is placed as a horizontal nav-bar and I'd like for it to
>   be shown when the page loads as if the user has already clicked on it.

You can achieve this by giving you menu items an `id` and open that menu in `jquery`.

```
<a href="#" id="menu1">Section 1 </a>
```

then add this to the script section of your page:

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu1").click();
});
```